# get notified on completion of all http requests

Tags: angular, typescript

What am trying to do is know when all http requests are completed.Am loading data in small chunks like this\

```
onLoadData(){

  do{

   this._reportService.getRawData(
      {
        //..pass pagination info here
      }
    ).subscribe(
      res=>{
        this.fetchedtrucks += this.paginatorval;
      }
    )

  i+= this.paginatorval;

}while(i<this.totalRecords);


//always check if its completed 

setTimeout(()=>{
  if(this.fetchedtrucks >= this.totalRecords){
    this.completedLOadingData();
    console.log("Completed loading trucks"); //executed
  }

}, 500);

}
```

Now he dataLoading complete function

```
  completedLOadingData(){

   console.log("Updating DOM");
   this.dataLoadingCmplete = true;
   this.exportstart = false;
   this._appRef.tick();
 }
```

as from the above i would like to listen to when totalfetched is equal to totalrecords hence i can determine that all data has been pulled

Now in the html i have

```
  <button type="button" *ngIf="!dataLoadingCmplete" class="btn btn-danger" >Export</button>

<button type="button" *ngIf="dataLoadingCmplete" class="btn btn-danger"> Genrate </button>
```

But even after the data has completed the button status does not change. What could be wrong?

Comment: Your two buttons are going to look exactly the same.  What "button status" change are you expecting to see?

Comment: But ngIf should change one button to another using the status dataLoadingCmplete

Comment: so basically hide and display another upon dataLoadingCmplete status change

Comment: Yes, but it will hide one and replace it with one that looks exactly the same.  How will you know that it has changed?  What difference are you expecting?  They both say "Export" and have the same CSS...

Comment: i had copied wrongly see the change of name as it is in my local computer one is generate and the other export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code assumes that all of the requests will complete within half a second.  Probably not a reasonable assumption.  Try doing the completion check within the HTTP response callback.

```
onLoadData() {
    do {
        this._reportService.getRawData({ /* ... */ })
            .subscribe(
                response => {
                    this.fetchedtrucks += this.paginatorval;

                    if (this.fetchedtrucks >= this.totalRecords) {
                        this.completedLOadingData();
                    }
                }
            )

        i += this.paginatorval;

    } while (i < this.totalRecords);
}
```

It is also assuming that `this.paginatorval` isn't being updated anywhere else during the duration of the data loading, or `i` and `fetchedtrucks` won't align.  Your `_reportService` also needs to be returning a valid `Observable`.  If there are still issues you may need to step through it in the debugger.

Comment: OOh i see why i shouldnt overreason. Thanks this works.

Comment: could you also help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46576637/adding-items-to-the-end-of-an-array-in-typescript